# MYSQL Trigger update not working as expected when value is updated

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, database-trigger

Looking to use a trigger on a MYSQL table when the row is updated, anytime the row is updated. Only setting the id if the id field is null

```
create trigger before_id_update
BEFORE UPDATE
ON USERS for each row
BEGIN
if id iS NULL THEN 
SET id = username
END IF;
END
```

Currently nothing is happening when the table row is updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should raise a syntax error, since `id` and `username` are undefined variables. If you want to access the values on the updated row, use pseudo-tables `NEW` or `OLD`.

You also need a `delimiter` statement at the beginning of your code, and the `set` command should be terminated with a semi-colon.

You presumably want:

```
delimiter //

create trigger before_id_update
before update on users 
for each row
begin
    if new.id is null then 
        set new.id = new.username;
    end if;
end
//

delimiter ;
```

Note that this only makes sense if both `id` and `username` have the same datatype (which is not obvious from their names).

Comment: Thanks, I did update to your code, but as you pointed out  **id** is varchar(255) and **username** is varchar(100).  Would that explain why the update is not working?

Comment: @jmadd: this way, it will work. Both are strings, and you are assigning the shortest string to the longuest one, so no issue there.

Comment: Thanks, no errors but the value is not being updated.

Comment: @jmadd: then it means the new `id` is not `null`. Maybe it is the empty string?  Try `if new.id is null or new.id = ''`.